# How do I add a touchstart eventListener to a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a mobile website (specifically for mobile Safari) and I want to add a touchStart eventListener for a `select` element. How do I do it?

I can do this easily enough for divs (that then act like buttons) i.e.
`document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("touchstart", startBtn, true);`

and this will then fire startBtn very quickly when the `div` is clicked.

But with my `select` element it takes longer than I would like to load the drop down list (as it handles it as a mouse click, I think, and waits 300ms to see if there is another click coming).

Comment: bind touchend to the select element instead, and try it out. Or why not use .click() directly?